# Flagging an email before sending using any class of System.net.mail namespace

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to "Flag an email" for followup using SMTPClient/MailMessage classes in .NET?

Comment: Yes... and I found the answer my self...
http://www.asp101.com/tips/index.asp?id=142

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that the flag is not part of the POP/MIME/SMTP specs and is simply a sorting feature offered by many applications. You can set the importance high, normal and low.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage
{
    Priority = MailPriority.High,
    Subject = "High priority message."
};
```